# Set Write access permissions while configuring a Glue job

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, permissions, hdfs, aws-glue

I am trying to execute an AWS-GLUE job that creates a temporary file on the disk. However, when trying to write a sparkDataFrame:

```
dydf = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
connection_type = 's3',
connection_options = {'paths': ['s3://some-bucket/test.csv']},
format = 'csv')
sdf = dydf.toDF()
sdf.coalesce(1).write.csv(filepath)
```

on the disk, I get the following error:

> Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): Permission denied: user=root, access=WRITE, inode="/":hdfs:hadoop:drwxr-xr-x

How can I set/grant these permissions to write a file to disk for the Glue job?

Comment: can you update your post with full pyspark script?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy: Updated the post. I got my task done by converting the sparkDataFrame to pandasDataFrame. However, the behaviour feels strange.

Comment: It looks like filepath is set to a hdfs location and not s3. Can you edit with what the filepath variable is set to. Also, why not use the `persist` method set to `DISK_ONLY` if you want to store something to temporary disk?

Comment: @Zambonilli Yes, I wanted to save some data to the disk. Hence, filepath variable was set to a hdfs location. When I converted the sparkDataFrame to a pandasDataFrame, I was able to write the data without changing any permissions. That was strange but it worked for me to get the job done.